# Regex to extract portion of URL

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

The URL could be one of the following:

```
http://spappsdev.domain.com/sites/sitename/
http://spappsdev/sites/sitename/
```

I'd like to extract "spappsdev" in a way that would work for both URL's. Is this even possible? I'd hate to have to run two regex commands.

Comment: In which language? Is this in JavaScript? There are better alternatives that regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this using [*look around*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
^https?://\K[^/\.]+
```

Or :

```
(?<=://)[^/\.]+
```

One real life example using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in a shell :

```
$ perl -lne 'm!(?<=://)[^/\.]+! and print $&' file
spappsdev
spappsdev
```

To assign the result to a shell variable :

```
$ var="$(perl -lne 'm!(?<=://)[^/\.]+! and print $&' file)"
$ echo "$var"
```

Comment: This got the portion i was wanting to extract but now i want to assign it to a variable. How would i assign the extracted portion to a "$1" so that i could replace the whole string with it?

Comment: You should add at least your programming language in your original post by adding the needed tag

Comment: Its for Nintex Workflows. I have a Pattern field, Replacement text field and input field.

Comment: oO seems not a real _programming language_ AFAIK. Added perl in a shell example

Comment: I used this (?<=://)[^/\.]+ one and switched to a extract instead of replace and it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\bhttps?:\/\/([^\/.]+)
```

And grab matched group #1

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eG0vW1/2)

Comment: how do i grab a matched group? i tried $1 but didn't get anything.

Comment: Depends of your programming language

Comment: @reub77: What language/tool are you using for regex?

Comment: Nintex Workflows is where i'm building this. I'm using the Replace text option.

Comment: Sorry don't know much about that but if it support captured groups then this should work.